# Notepad in android - crashing SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

I want create my own Notepad, similar like in tutorial on Android site. When I try to run my application, Eclipse opens new tab - "activitythread.performlaunchactivity(activitythread$activityclientrecord intent) line: 2059" with statement "Source not found. Edit source lookup Path...". There is my code:

```
package com.notatnik;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private NotesDB mDB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDB = new NotesDB(this);
        mDB.open();
        fillData();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void saveNote(View view) {
        TextView textField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String note = textField.getText().toString();
        mDB.createNote(note);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void fillData() {
        Cursor cursor = mDB.fetchAllNotes();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item_list, cursor,
            new String[] {NotesDB.COLUMN_CONTENT}, new int[] {R.id.textView_content}, 0);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    } 
}
```

Logcat:

```
    02-07 17:28:40.622: D/AndroidRuntime(2600): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
02-07 17:28:40.622: D/AndroidRuntime(2600): CheckJNI is ON
02-07 17:28:40.662: D/dalvikvm(2600): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
02-07 17:28:40.672: D/dalvikvm(2600): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
02-07 17:28:40.702: D/dalvikvm(2600): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
02-07 17:28:40.702: D/dalvikvm(2600): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
02-07 17:28:41.463: D/AndroidRuntime(2600): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
02-07 17:28:41.513: D/AndroidRuntime(2600): Shutting down VM
02-07 17:28:41.523: D/dalvikvm(2600): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 78% free 466K/2048K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 14ms
02-07 17:28:41.523: D/dalvikvm(2600): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
02-07 17:28:42.152: D/AndroidRuntime(2613): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
02-07 17:28:42.152: D/AndroidRuntime(2613): CheckJNI is ON
02-07 17:28:42.203: D/dalvikvm(2613): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
02-07 17:28:42.212: D/dalvikvm(2613): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
02-07 17:28:42.242: D/dalvikvm(2613): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
02-07 17:28:42.242: D/dalvikvm(2613): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
02-07 17:28:43.113: D/AndroidRuntime(2613): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
02-07 17:28:43.153: I/ActivityManager(148): Force stopping package com.notatnik uid=10044
02-07 17:28:43.153: I/ActivityManager(148): Killing proc 2260:com.notatnik/u0a44: force stop
02-07 17:28:43.203: I/ActivityManager(148): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.notatnik/.MainActivity u=0} from pid 2613
02-07 17:28:43.334: D/dalvikvm(148): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 260K, 9% free 11697K/12743K, paused 89ms, total 99ms
02-07 17:28:43.334: W/InputMethodManagerService(148): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@415cb158 attribute=null
02-07 17:28:43.422: D/AndroidRuntime(2613): Shutting down VM
02-07 17:28:43.422: D/dalvikvm(2632): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
02-07 17:28:43.442: D/dalvikvm(2613): GC_CONCURRENT freed 102K, 76% free 492K/2048K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 15ms
02-07 17:28:43.442: D/jdwp(2613): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
02-07 17:28:43.442: D/dalvikvm(2613): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
02-07 17:28:43.453: I/AndroidRuntime(2613): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder_3' failed
02-07 17:28:43.472: I/ActivityManager(148): Start proc com.notatnik for activity com.notatnik/.MainActivity: pid=2632 uid=10044 gids={1028}
02-07 17:28:43.843: E/Trace(2632): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-07 17:28:43.872: W/ActivityThread(2632): Application com.notatnik is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
02-07 17:28:43.892: I/System.out(2632): Sending WAIT chunk
02-07 17:28:43.902: I/dalvikvm(2632): Debugger is active
02-07 17:28:44.092: I/System.out(2632): Debugger has connected
02-07 17:28:44.092: I/System.out(2632): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-07 17:28:44.293: I/System.out(2632): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-07 17:28:44.503: I/System.out(2632): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-07 17:28:44.703: I/System.out(2632): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-07 17:28:44.915: I/System.out(2632): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-07 17:28:45.125: I/System.out(2632): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-07 17:28:45.325: I/System.out(2632): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-07 17:28:45.569: I/System.out(2632): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-07 17:28:45.785: I/System.out(2632): debugger has settled (1452)
02-07 17:28:53.385: W/ActivityManager(148): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
02-07 17:28:53.814: W/ActivityManager(148): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{413ede80 com.notatnik/.MainActivity}
02-07 17:29:00.092: D/dalvikvm(2632): Debugger has detached; object registry had 312 entries
02-07 17:29:00.092: D/AndroidRuntime(2632): Shutting down VM
02-07 17:29:00.102: W/dalvikvm(2632): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
02-07 17:29:00.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2632): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-07 17:29:00.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2632): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.notatnik/com.notatnik.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
02-07 17:29:00.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2632):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
02-07 17:29:00.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2632):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
02-07 17:29:00.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2632):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
02-07 17:29:00.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2632):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
02-07 17:29:00.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2632):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-07 17:29:00.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2632):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-07 17:29:00.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2632):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-07 17:29:00.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2632):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 17:29:00.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2632):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-07 17:29:00.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2632):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-07 17:29:00.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2632):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-07 17:29:00.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2632):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-07 17:29:00.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2632): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
02-07 17:29:00.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2632):     at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
02-07 17:29:00.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2632):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:259)
02-07 17:29:00.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2632):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
02-07 17:29:00.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2632):     at com.notatnik.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
02-07 17:29:00.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2632):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
02-07 17:29:00.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2632):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
02-07 17:29:00.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2632):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
02-07 17:29:00.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2632):     ... 11 more
02-07 17:29:00.232: W/ActivityManager(148):   Force finishing activity com.notatnik/.MainActivity
02-07 17:29:00.422: D/dalvikvm(148): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 342K, 8% free 11758K/12743K, paused 100ms, total 115ms
02-07 17:29:00.986: W/ActivityManager(148): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{413ede80 com.notatnik/.MainActivity}
02-07 17:29:01.263: W/EGL_emulation(279): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
```

I've not finished, but I think that this simple code should compile. I found out that the problem is SimpleCursorAdapter in fillData() method, but I don't know what is wrong. I'm begging with programming for Android. Sorry for my bad english...

Comment: The "Source not found" page is not the error that crashed your app, please cut & paste the red LogCat errors into your question so we can see what is happening.

Comment: if `ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);` causing error then use `android.R.id.list` instead of `R.id.list`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about Logcat. @ρяσѕρєя K - the problem is SimpleCursorAdapter, when I comment it, code works.

Comment: I'm not sure this is actually an answer to your question, but you can't do what you are trying to do.  You must not try to load the cursor on the UI thread, as you are attempting to do.  That may work sometimes, but it will get you an ANR.  Use the LoaderManager and a CursorLoader.

Comment: While it is best to perform potentially slow operations, like reading from a database, on another thread, that is a more advanced topic and it shouldn't crash your app. Are there any more errors in the LogCat?  Do you see an "Application Not Responding" popup?

Comment: Only "Unfortunately, Notatnik has stopped."

Comment: Hmmm... when I change to `SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item_list, null,
   new String[] {NotesDB.COLUMN_CONTENT}, new int[] {R.id.textView_content}, 0);` (null instead cursor) app works. There is something wrong with cursor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED

The Cursor MUST include a column named _id or this class will not work.
I changed the method fetchAllNotes() in NotesDB class:

```
public Cursor fetchAllNotes () {
        return mDB.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {COLUMN_CONTENT}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }
```

to

```
public Cursor fetchAllNotes () {
            return mDB.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {_ID, COLUMN_CONTENT}, null, null, null, null, null);
        }
```

Works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From your LogCat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

This means that in `res/layout/activity_main.xml` your ListView must have this attribute:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should custom listview adapter.